# docker Can't get ENTRYPOINT and CMD to work

Tags: docker

I have to start two services in one container

I have tried all kinds of variations, and think this is how it is supposed to look. But clearly I am missing something. The container exists right away!

```
CMD ["start"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/dockCtrl"]
```

I also read that I am not supposed to use systemd / service and tried the command direct with no success. (see uncommented command)

build and run command:

```
docker build -t robotamer/citadel citadel
docker run -d --name="citadel" --hostname="mail" 24fcf023c95e
```

I can enter the container using `-it bash` rather then `-d` and use the `dockCtrl` bash script just fine.

dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:testing
MAINTAINER RoboTamer <xxxx@gmail.com>
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y citadel-suite nano rsync && \
    apt-get clean

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND interactive
EXPOSE 25/tcp 587/tcp 143/tcp 993/tcp 995/tcp 5222 2020/tcp 504/tcp
COPY dockCtrl /sbin/
CMD ["start"]
ENTRYPOINT ["dockCtrl", "start"]
```

dockCtrl (-rwxr-xr-x):

```
#!/bin/bash

if test $1 = "start"
then
    # exec /usr/sbin/citserver -d -x3 -lmail -t/dev/null
    # exec /usr/sbin/webcit -d -p80 -f -c
    service citadel start
    service webcit start
fi

if test $1 = "stop"
then
    service citadel stop
    service webcit stop
fi

if test $1 = "clean"
then
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
fi
```

Comment: Why did you delete your question and repost it?

Comment: I had made a small change and was building in the background. And for a moment it looked like it worked but it didn't so I reposted. Sorry for the inconvenience. I was trying to remove before before bothering someone, sorry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to note here:

- When using `ENTRYPOINT`, the `CMD` gets appended to the `ENTRYPOINT`. Your current `Dockerfile` will run `dockCtrl start start`. This probably wasn't what you intended.
- The dockCtrl script appears to start services and then exit, thus, the container exits. You will need to fire them up with something that can stay in the foreground (supervisord, runit, etc.).